# NodeJS, multiple if may return headers (and fails)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, if-statement

**Updated with Promise example.**

I'm running NodeJS and are having issues with multiple `if`-statements and `return`-statements.
I'm trying to use `Promise` at it might seem as a way to go.

This is my example code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pgPromise = require('pg-promise')();

const db = pgPromise(CONNECTION_STRING);

app.use((req, res) => {

    var message = "";


    promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        message += "promise1";
        if (false) {
            reject(message);
        }
    });


    promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (true) {
            db.one('SELECT 1')
                .then(row => {
                    message += " promise2";
                    resolve(message);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    message += " error";
                    reject(message);
                });
        }
    });

    var printResult = (results) => {console.log("Results = ", results, "message = ", message)}

    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(printResult);

    return res.json({ message: message });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

It doesn't seem to wait for the Promise 2 to finish the database query.

How can I make sure the database query is done before return any statement?

Comment: That code will not have that effect. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: People considering answering this question, please note that three people have posted answers (two have been deleted at the time of this comment) that failed to account for the return statements in the question.

Comment: Haven't got a useful answer yet - so all answers are welcome.

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: Tried to update the entire question so it's easier to understand the challenge.

Comment: Another update to show problem...

Answer (score 0):

The code execution doesn't stop on Promise.all, you need to move the return statement to the Promise.all callback, and return the Promise returned by Promise.all.

```
return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(() => {
  printResult();
  return res.json({ message: message });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Node JS runs asynchronously it doesn't wait for input1, inpu2, input3 to finish before executing final line(return res.json({ error: false });).

You need to use Promise to handle the sequence. Find the code below.

```
let input1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  if (typeof req.body.input1 != "undefined") {
    // do something
    resolve('Success');
  } else {
    reject('Error');
  }
});

let input2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  if (typeof req.body.input2 != "undefined") {
    // do something
    resolve('Success');
  } else {
    reject('Error');
  }
});

let input3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  if (typeof req.body.input3 != "undefined") {
    // do something
    resolve('Success');
  } else {
    reject('Error');
  }
});


input1.then((value) => {
  return res.json({ error: true });
})
  .catch((e) => {
    input2.then((value) => {
      return res.json({ error: true });
    })
      .catch((e) => {
        input3.then((value) => {
          return res.json({ error: true });
        })
          .catch((e) => {
            return res.json({ error: false });
          })
      })
  })
```

If you want to handle all inputs asynchronously, use promise.all().

Comment: "Since Node JS runs asynchronously" — Node.JS doesn't run asynchronously. Some functions do. `res.json` is not one of them.

Comment: Seems not to solve the issue - if input1 is undefined it returns Error - which it shouldn't. It should simply continue.